# How to run a postinstall script after

Tags: yarnpkg-v3

I am migrating from `yarn version 1.22` to `yarn v3.2.3`. I have a `prepare` script that was running automatically after install.

My `prepare` script generates some files (FIY Nuxt 3 generated files).

It does not run anymore on yarn 3, and how can I get the same effect? I don't find it on https://yarnpkg.com/advanced/lifecycle-scripts.
Maybe I am misreading.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?  I'm running into the same issue.

Comment: @gabaum10 I posted it

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have finally found a solution:

1. Install the [Yarn plugin after install](https://github.com/mhassan1/yarn-plugin-after-install): `yarn plugin import https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mhassan1/yarn-plugin-after-install/v0.3.1/bundles/@yarnpkg/plugin-after-install.js`.

- See the command in the README to get the latest version.

2. In a .yarnrc.yml at the root of your project, add your command: `afterInstall: <your-command>`

Comment: is there anything similar for pre-install?